# Delegating to another action in Ramaze

Tags: ruby, ramaze

I'd like to delegate to the Show action from the Index action if an id was passed. I can't seem to get it to work, what am I doing wrong here?

```
require 'ramaze'
require 'slim'

class UsersController < Ramaze::Controller
    engine :slim

    def index(id=nil)
        if id
            render_full "/users/show/#{id}" #id was passed, "show" the item
        end
        #alright just render the "index.slim" here...
    end

    def show(id)
        u=User[id] #ORM stuff...
    end
end

Ramaze.start
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `return render_full(...)` opposed to just `render_full()`, without this the code below it will be executed regardless of whether or not an ID was specified.

Comment: Sorry, `return render_full "/users/show/#{id}" if id` doesn't work. From what I observed, returning a string from the action works (as expected) but not if you set up a view engine. I seem to get strange errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `return show(id)` instead of `render_full "/users/show/#{id}"`

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work either! Please see my comment on Yorick's answer.